# Beautifulsoup and Soupstrainer for getting links dont work with hasattr, returning always true

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, hasattr

i am using Beautifulsoup4 and Soupstrainer with Python 3.3 for getting all links from a webpage. The following is the important code-snippet:

```
r = requests.get(adress, headers=headers)
for link in BeautifulSoup(r.text, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if hasattr(link, 'href'):
```

I tested some webpages and it works very well but today when using

```
adress = 'http://www.goldentigercasino.de/'
```

I recognized that hasattr(link, 'href') always returns TRUE even when there is no such 'href' field, like in the goldentigercasino.de example.
Because of that im getting troubles for late using link['href'] because its simply not there.

I also tried a workaround like this:

```
test = requests.get('http://www.goldentigercasino.de/')
for link in BeautifulSoup(test.text, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a',{'href': not None})):
```

That works as wanted Except that it also returns the Doctype:

```
HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"
```

Which is causing also trouble for the same reasons as above.

My question: Why does hasattr always returns true and how can I fix that? And if there is no possibility with hasattr, how can i fix my workaround that its not returning the DOCTYPE?

Many Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hasattr()` is the *wrong* test; it tests if there is a `a.href` attribute, and BeautifulSoup dynamically turns attributes into searches for children. HTML tag attributes are *not* translated into Python attributes.

Use dictionary-style testing instead; you loop over *all* elements which can include the `DocType` instance, so I use `getattr()` to not break on objects that don't have attributes:

```
if 'href' in getattr(link, 'attrs', {}):
```

You can also instruct `SoupStrainer` to only match `a` tags with a `href` attribute by using `href=True` as a [keyword argument filter](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments) (`not None` just means `True` in any case):

```
for link in BeautifulSoup(test.text, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a', href=True)):
```

This still includes the HTML declaration of course; search for just `a` links:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(test.text, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a', href=True))
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print link
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but ur last code-line gives me the same result than my workaround. Why is it returning the DOCTYPE? But i will have a look into the dictionary-style, but am still interested in the DOCTYPE case, it doesnt make sense to me...

Comment: @zwieback86: Because the doctype is never filtered, nor are text elements. You are looping over the *full* object, not just link elements. See my last updates.