# BeautifulSoup unexpectedly matches <!doctype>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some simple code...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

text = """<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<div></div>
<div class='detail'></div>
<div></div>
<div class='detail'></div>
<div></div>"""

for div in BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml', parse_only = SoupStrainer('div', attrs = { 'class': 'detail' })):
    print(div)
```

...which I expect to print two divs with class 'detail'. Instead, I get the two divs and the doctype, for some reason:

```
html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
<div class="detail"></div>
<div class="detail"></div>
```

What's happening here? How can I avoid matching the doctype?

**EDIT**

Here is one filtering method I found:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer, Doctype
...
for div in BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml', parse_only = SoupStrainer('div', attrs = { 'class': 'detail' })):
    if type(div) is Doctype:
        continue
```

Still interested in knowing how to avoid the situation where I have to filter out the doctype while using `SoupStrainer`.

The reason I want to use `SoupStrainer` instead of `find_all` is beacuse `SoupStrainer` is almost two times faster, which adds up to ~30 seconds of a difference with just a 1000 parsed pages:

```
def soup_strainer(text):
    [div for div in BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml', parse_only = SoupStrainer('div', attrs = { 'class': 'detail' })) if type(div) is not Doctype]

def find_all(text):
    [div for div in BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml').find_all('div', { 'class': 'detail' })]

from timeit import timeit    
print( timeit('soup_strainer(text)', number = 1000, globals = globals()) ) # 38.091634516923584
print( timeit('find_all(text)', number = 1000, globals = globals()) ) # 65.1686057066947
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943992/beautifulsoup-and-soupstrainer-for-getting-links-dont-work-with-hasattr-returni) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988884/lxml-incorrectly-parsing-the-doctype-while-looking-for-links) post - I think they will resolve you issue and answer your question...

Comment: if you want to filter out `!DOCTYPE` also, use `find_all` instead of `soupstrainer`...

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use `SoupStrainer` for this task.  Instead, the built-in `findAll` method should do what you want.  Here is the code I tested and seems to work fine:

```
[div for div in BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml').findAll('div', {'class':'detail'})]
```

This will create a list of the `div`'s you are looking for, excluding the `DOCTYPE`

Hope this helps.

Comment: `findAll` is quite slow compared to `SoupStrainer`.

Comment: @AlexUndefined I agree; however, `SoupStrainer` is not going to filter `doctype` or `text` elements, it's just how it works.  See this post for more evidence https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943992/beautifulsoup-and-soupstrainer-for-getting-links-dont-work-with-hasattr-returni